# How to force a SLOW charge over USB

Tags: usb, charging, android

It is often asked how to charge faster over USB, but I want to do the opposite, charge overnight as slowly as possible, to preserve battery life.

If at all possible I'd like to limit charge current to 500 mA.

Some cheapo / bad chargers already do this, but I'd like to build a cable that allows me to use any charger and have the cable fool my phone into thinking it cannot pull any more than 500 mA.

How could this be done?

- Open data lines?
- Serial resistors in power lines?
- A diode in the positive line to reduce the voltage?

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Get some USB-C to micro-USB and backwards adapters, then chain them. This will hopefully kill any usb-c specific signals on the way.